# Связи между элементами MVC

Tags: mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Может ли кто-нибудь пояснить связи между элементами MVC на примере [этой картинки](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/ModelViewControllerDiagram2.svg/313px-ModelViewControllerDiagram2.svg.png)?

Или поправить меня:

1. Controller → Model — это непосредственное изменение controller'ом данных модели.
2. Model → Viev — это модель уведомляет viev об изменениях, в ней произошедших.
3. Viev → Model — это viev берёт данные из модели.
4. Viev → Controller — это viev уведомляет controller о действиях пользователя (кнопочку, к примеру, нажал).
5. Controller → Viev — **а эта связь, по моему, лишняя** и противоречит принципу MVC «controller разрабатывается независемо от viev, и взаимодействует с ним только через модель».

Comment: Поменьше заморачивайтесь принципами, которые пытаются навязывать "Большие ученые". Действуйте "по обстановке" в соответствии со "здравым смыслом".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В идеальной ситуации, да, контроллер ничего не должен знать о представлении, но на практике это не всегда так.
Поэтому соглашусь с первым комментарием.